# How many keywords can I put in my page for google spiders

Tags: seo, google, keywords

How many keywords can I put in my page for google spiders ?

Comment: How about writing good content and letting the keywords just naturally happen? If you write for search engines you're going to fail because you're ignoring your target audience.

Comment: it means my page has too many?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you speak about meta keywords: **0**

[Google does not use the keywords meta tag in web ranking](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)

Take much care about the content of your `<title>` tag, all the words you use in the headings tags (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, ...), and the quality of the content of your page.

You can also have a lot of precious guidance here:

- [Search Engine Optimization (SEO)](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35291)
- [Webmaster Guidelines](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769)
- [Keyword stuffing](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66358)

Answer (score 1):

G. Qyy is right, meta keywords are useless in today's SEO world.

In terms of targeting content for search engines, I'm a bit old school and like single-focused keyword targeting. Now, Google will likely - over time - find a cluster of keywords but as you're writing I'd think about just one or potentially two terms (if it's a modifier.)

So, if you're writing about a Purple Cheetah, then *that* should be the keyword target, but you might also target Fast Purple Cheetah.

While writing good content can sometimes work, there are plenty of examples where that fails. So I recommend writing for search engines.

http://www.blindfiveyearold.com/search-engines-are-readers-too

It's **actually** about writing good web content - which will benefit human and bot readers alike.

Answer (score 0):

five to ten keyword is good for optimization.

Comment: Welcome to webmasters. Can you give us a link to something that backs this up?